# How do I map my database to my model?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm using NHibernate 3.3.2.4 (Not Fluent)... I'm trying to map a database model to an application model and I'm coming unstuck.

I have the following database structure (simplified for brevity):

```
LibraryItems
------------
Id UniqueIdentifier Primary Key,
UserId UniqueIdentifier Foreign Key References Users(UserId),
Type SmallInt,             --Book, Magazine etc.
ProductId UniqueIdentifier --Links to UserBooks When Type = 1
                           --         UserMagazines When Type = 2

UserBooks
---------
ProductId UniqueIdentifier Unique Foreign Key References Books(Id),
--Other fields pertaining to books

UserMagazines
-------------
ProductId UniqueIdentifier Unique Foreign Key References Magazines(Id),
--Other fields pertaining to magazines

UserBookmarks
-------------
Id UniqueIdentifier Primary Key,
LibraryItemId UniqueIdentifier Foreign Key References LibraryItems(Id),
BookmarkLocation NVarChar(100)
```

I also have the following application model

```
public enum LibraryItemType
{
    Book = 1,
    Magazine = 2
}

public abstract class LibraryItem
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }   //ProductId
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    abstract public LibraryItemType Type { get; }
}

public abstract class ReadableLibraryItem : LibraryItem
{
    public Bookmark CurrentPosition { get; set; }
}

public class UserBook : ReadableLibraryItem
{
    public override LibraryItemType Type { get { return LibraryItemType.Book; } }
    //Other properties pertaining to books
}

public class UserMagazine : ReadableLibraryItem
{
    public override LibraryItemType Type { get { return LibraryItemType.Magazine; } }
    //Other properties pertaining to magazines
}
```

I am completely at a loss as to how to map from the data model in my database to the application model... so far I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<hibernate-mapping default-cascade="save-update" 
                   assembly="Model" 
                   namespace="Model.Library" 
                   default-lazy="false" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">

  <class name="LibraryItem" table="LibraryItems" optimistic-lock="version">

    <id name="Id" type="Guid" unsaved-value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">
      <generator class="assigned"/>
    </id>

    <discriminator column="Type" type="Int32" />
    <property name="UserId" type="Guid" not-null="true" />
    <property name="ProductId" type="Guid" not-null="true" />
    <property name="Type" type="Model.Library.LibraryItemType, Model" not-null="true" />

    <joined-subclass name="ReadableLibraryItem">

      <one-to-one name="CurrentPosition" type="Model.Library.Bookmark" class="Bookmark" property-ref="LibraryItemId" />

      <joined-subclass name="UserBook" table="UserBooks" lazy="false" discriminator-value="1">
        <key column="Id" />
      </joined-subclass>

      <joined-subclass name="UserMagazineIssue" table="UserMagazineIssues" lazy="false" discriminator-value="2">
        <key column="Id" />
      </joined-subclass>

    </joined-subclass>

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My problems appear to be two-fold.

1. My sub-types UserBooks and UserMagazines in my application model are actually SubTypes of SubTypes and I have no idea how to model that in my hbm file.
2. The discriminator is in the LibraryItems table, but applied in the sub-sub-class.

Answer (score 0):

It’s been a while since I created mappings manually, but in the past I have used Mapping generators such as this one: http://nmg.codeplex.com/

Is important to NHibernate (Just as EF) provides mapping from tables to classes. If you have sub-types, I would treat them as separate classes and add a default “where” clause on your mapping.

So you would have 3 mapping files for each one of the sub-types:

- ReadableLibraryItem
- UserBook
- UserMagazine

Again, it has been a while since I’ve done manual mappings, but that is how I would go about it.

One more thing, it used to be that all the properties needed to be “virtual”, I am not sure if that is still the case.

Hope this helps,